# POSIX-compatible shell script: Start with a shebang?

Tags: shell, posix, sh

I'm writing a shell script, and want it to be POSIX-compatible. I was always under the impression that a shell script should start with a shebang (`#!`), but I found [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) online:

> If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.

Should I start my script with a `#!` line or not if I want it to be POSIX-compliant?

Comment: I imagine that's the spec language that allows for shebang lines to work in the first place. You can read http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ for much more information about shebang lines.

Answer (score 1):

Things change.  It *used* to be the case that an unmarked (no `#!`) script would run the Bourne shell, but now it is unspecified, as you say.

"Recent" versions of Korn shell and Bash run themselves (i.e., either `bash` or `ksh`) if no `#!` is present.  However `zsh` runs `sh` (POSIX shell).   So it depends on the shell that runs the script.

If it is not a shell, then a C layer will call `execve` (or a variant of it).  The POSIX standard is vague on which shell is used, but the GNU version of `execve` says:

"*execve() executes the program pointed to by filename. filename must be either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the form:*"

```
#! interpreter [optional-arg]
```

My advice is to always supply a `#!` line - it is a small price to pay for certainty.  If for some reason that line is not required then it is just a comment, since it starts `#`.

Comment: POSIX has probably decided to clarify the historical conflict between the behaviors (as you described in 1st and 2nd paragraphs) and declared it "unspecified" so that users do not expect consistent behavior between systems and shells. The POSIX tends to concentrate on the commonalities, and often leaves out the areas where there is no consensus among OSs.